# Django template tag doesnt work

Tags: python, django

template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='mod')
def mod(value, arg):
    return value % arg
```

using:

```
{% load tree_filters %}

<script type="text/javascript">
...
                {% for child in user.tree_node1.grandchildren.all %}
                    {
                        id: {{ child.account.id }},
                        label: "{{ child }}",
                        shape: 'box',
                        color: colors[{{ child.level|mod: 10 }}]
                    },
                {% endfor %}

            ]);
...
        </script>
```

I actually tried to use django_math_filters package's "mod"but I've got the same error:

```
mod requires 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Where I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're allowed a space before the `10`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ child.level|mod:'10' }}
```

You need to remove the space before the argument you pass and pass the argument as string. Django does not allow spaces in template filters.